# C++ error C2664: Cannot convert 'mw::World' to 'mw::World'

Tags: c++

I attempted to research this error, but it is really confusing how something cannot be converted to itself.  Though I have an idea as to why.

The error arises within this function:

```
//GameObject.h

#include "BasicComponents.h"

namespace mw
{

class GameObject
{
public:
    void handleEvents(mw::World world, sf::RenderWindow& screen, mw::EventList& events) 
    {
        myInput->handleEvents(*this, screen, events);

        //Passing world here causes the error
        myPhysics->handleEvents(*this, world, screen, events);

        myGraphics->handleEvents(*this, screen, events);
    }
};

}//end of namespace
```

The function that gets the error is this:

```
//BasicComponents.h

namespace mw
{

//Needed for parameters
    class GameObject;
    class World;
///////////////////////

class PhysicsComponent : public mw::Component
{
public:
    virtual void handleEvents(GameObject& object, mw::World world, sf::RenderWindow& screen, mw::EventList& events) = 0;

};

}//end of namespace
```

I believe the issue lies within the incomplete type used in BasicComponents.h.  However, it is needed in order for me to let the function know that the class exists somewhere and we will be doing something with it when we know about it.  If this is the problem, how do I fix it?  Otherwise, why does this happen?

Edit: copy constructor:

```
//World.h

//Copy Constructor
World(const World& me) 
{
    myMap = me.myMap;
    myObjects = me.myObjects; 
}
```

.

MCVE:

```
// Class1.h

#pragma once

#include "Class2.h"

namespace test
{

    class Class1
    {
    public:

        void function(test::Class3& c3)
        {
            myC2->function(*this, c3);
        }

        Class1() {}
        ~Class1(){}

    private:
        Class2* myC2;
    };

}//end of namespace


// Class2.h

#pragma once

namespace test
{

    class Class1;
    class Class3;

    class Class2
    {
    public:

        virtual void function(Class1 c1, Class3 c3) = 0;

        void otherFunction(){}

        Class2(){}
        ~Class2(){}

    private:

    };

}//end of namespace
```

Comment: Does `mw::World` have a copy constructor? Is it public?

Comment: It does have a copy constructor, and yes, it is public.

Comment: @Uulamock Show us the copy-constructor.

Comment: Is it possible for you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: don't know, but isn't the problem that the mw:World is in a different namespace than the BasicComponents.h where you declare  "class World"?

Comment: @R Sahu I shall try to, though it may take a while.

Comment: @user2587326 They are all under the namespace mw.

Comment: including World.h from BasicComponents.h is not an option?

Comment: @Palo It would create a circular dependency.

Comment: Interesting new piece of information I came across, If I pass mw::World by reference it compiles, don't know why or if that means it is still a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be seeing some kind of warning/error for `void handleEvents(mw::World world, sf::RenderWindow& screen, mw::EventList& events)` about `mw::World` being incomplete.

Passing a class with pass-by-value needs to know the declaration of the class in order to know how much space is needed for the parameter. Even if you could trick the compiler, the size of the class is not known at that point so the wrong amount of space will be reserved for the parameter.

Passing a class with pass-by-reference doesn't have this limitation, the space needed for the parameter will be of a known size even if the class is not defined.

If possible pass a `const mw::World& world` instead of `mw::World world`, by changing it from a pass-by-value to pass-by-reference, GameObject.h will be able to use the forward declaration of `mw::World`.

Finally, I would also recommend moving the inline `handleEvents` to BasicComponents.cpp, wait until testing before inlining code and only inline code that causes performance problems. As Knuth said, "premature optimization is the root of all evil."